# Relacionamento de Tabelas - como fazer

Tags: mysql, lógica

Estou com problemas para entender como criar o relacionamento das tabelas.
O meu cenário é o abaixo:

Um `parceiro` pode ter vários `usuários`, porém um `usuário` só pode estar atrelado à um `parceiro`.
Um `usuário` pode cadastrar inúmeros `pedidos`, e esses `pedidos` estarão atrelados `usuário` que cadastrou e ao `parceiro` do usuário. Exemplo: `pedido` **a** está atrelado ao `usuário` **cesar** no qual este `usuário` está atrelado ao `parceiro` **parceiro x**.

Para realizar um novo `pedido` é necessário colocar o código (id) do `parceiro` e os dados do novo pedido, como: **nome, rg, cpf e email**

Neste `pedido` há uma `chave de vpn` no qual é única e sendo formada por **parceiro-cpf**. Em uma tabela `vpnCode` tem a `chave de vpn`, bytes recebidos, enviados, ip do servidor, ip real.

Uma `VPN` tem `chave de vpn`, o `parceiro` que a gerou, o `cpf` do `pedido`, o `rg` do `pedido`.

O que eu não consigo entender (estou há mais de uma semana tentando entender como fazer) é como fazer esses relacionamentos. Por favor, preciso de ajuda.

Comment: A relação USUARIO x PARCEIRO é 1 para 1 ou 1 para muitos?

Comment: Cada USUARIO pode ter apenas um PARCEIRO, mas cada PARCEIRO pode ter vários USUARIOS... Ou seja, 1 para 1

Comment: Penso que você precisa uma tabela de USUARIOS, uma de PARCEIROS,  uma de CHAVES_VPN, uma de USUARIO_PARCEIRO, uma de PARCEIROS_USUARIOS e CHAVES_PARCEIROS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que essa arquitetura deve resolver o seu problema.
Não coloquei todos os campos do VPN mas vc pode fazer vc mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se precisar do código que gera essas tabelas, veja abaixo:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`PARCEIRO`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`PARCEIRO` (
  `pk_parceiro` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cpf` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `RG` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `E-mail` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `outrosCampos` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_parceiro`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`USER`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`USER` (
  `pk_user` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `pk_father` INT NULL,
  `Name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `outrosCampos` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_user`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`USER_PARCEIROS`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`USER_PARCEIROS` (
  `fk_user` INT NOT NULL,
  `fk_parceiro` INT NOT NULL,
  `outrosCampos` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fk_user`, `fk_parceiro`),
  INDEX `fkp_idx` (`fk_parceiro` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fku`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fk_user`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`USER` (`pk_user`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fkp`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fk_parceiro`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PARCEIRO` (`pk_parceiro`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`vpnCode_Parc`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`vpnCode_Parc` (
  `pk_vpnCOde` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `vpnCode` VARCHAR(450) NOT NULL,
  `fkParceiro` INT NOT NULL,
  `outrosCampos` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_vpnCOde`),
  INDEX `fkkpar_idx` (`fkParceiro` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fkkpar`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fkParceiro`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`PARCEIRO` (`pk_parceiro`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

Se um usuário só pode ter um parceiro e este pode estar associado a múltiplos usuários então o modelo fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Zwitterion fiquei confuso em relação ao user_parceiro e usuário

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, 1 usuário pode ter ao menos 1 parceiro e 1 parceiro precisa ter ao menos 1 usário correto? Entáo é uma relação de muitos para muitos, com uma tabela intermediária. Fazendo uma primary key composta garante que vai haver somente uma entrada de usuário e parceiro.

Comment: Nota: a coluna pk_father em usuário é opcional. Com ela vc pode fazer uma análise de hierarquia.

Comment: zwitterion, segundo o OP nos comentarios, cada usuario pode ter apenas 1 parceiros, mas cada parceiros pode ter varios. A relação seria, no caso, `1:n`. @CesarA.Fonseca, caso seja isso mesmo, edite a pergunta e adicione essa informação para que as respostas fiquem de acordo também.

Comment: Por exemplo:

 `Usuários: a, b, c || Parceiro: x, y || Usuário a só pode estar em x ou y neste exemplo, e parceiro x ou y pode conter a, b e c`

Comment: Editei a pergunta pra ficar melhor pra entender

Comment: Ainda fica meio confuso. Existe a possibildade de um usuário não ter um parceiro? Fiz a edição baseado no cenario onde todos usuários possuirem um parceiro necessariamente.

Comment: Zwi minha dúvida foi solucionada, obrigado cara. Poderia me dar um único exemplo de como eu usaria o Join para consultar um Parceiro e mostrar todos os seus usuários?

Comment: Depende de como vc irá usar o parceiro. Pelo pk_parceiro ou pelo nome. O mais comum seria usar um selectBox, então vc irá recuperar o pk do parceiro atravéz de jquery e enviar para a seguinte sqlquery: `select U.Name, P.nome,P.cpf,P.RG,P.E-mail from  user as U
inner join PARCEIRO as P on (U.fk_Parceiro=P.pk_parceiro)
where U.fk_Parceiro = jsFkParceiro;` Duas sugestões: Mude esse npme de tabela que eu usei. Passe para usuario. E mude o nome do campo de E-mail para E_mail.

Comment: zwitterion existiria algum outro lugar para eu conversar contigo? Eu queria tirar algumas dúvidas, e se eu continuar a mandar por aqui ou criar outro tópico por uma dúvida semelhante irá poluir bastante...

Comment: @CesarA.Fonseca a resposta foi bem especifica, não custa dar +1 (além de marcar como solução), assim você ajuda quem te ajudou ;)

Comment: mande para o meu e-mail. igoralves1@hotmail.com. Respondo quando tiver tempo livre.

Comment: Pra eu marcar como  +1 preciso ter reputação a mais do que tenho...
@zwitterion obrigado man!